# Spring Boot REST service HTTPS in multiple server instance

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, https

I am using Spring Boot for creating microservice. I need to configure SSL so that services can be secured. I am able to do it using the below properties,

```
server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-alias=myKey
server.ssl.key-password=changeit
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:ssl-server.jks
```

But springboot jar will be placed in two server instances. We have two instance for one environment. So I will have two certificates each for instance. In this case I cant hard code the key store file as the file name is different.

I can think of any of the below:

have the same name for certificate and refer it in application.properties or
I need to pass this value of the key through arguments like below,

```
java -jar -Dcertificate.path=/etc/instance1.jks myspringboot.jar

server.ssl.key-store=${certificate.path}
```

What is the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can use environment variables for all similar specifics. Environment variable like `SERVER_SSL_KEY_STORE` will have a higher priority in runtime. If you need to store values to some secure store, you can use a spring vault.

Answer (score 0):

I would use multiple application properties files, one for each instance:

https://sodocumentation.net/spring-boot/topic/6334/create-and-use-of-multiple-application-properties-files